# jqGrid programmatically select row

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid and I want to setselection for the row of subgrid.

I have two grid
"First Grid" is parent grid and "Second Grid" is subgrid as grid or mean the Detail grid for Parent Grid.

I want when user click on the row of parent grid (First Grid), the detail grid programmatically select the top row.

This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#list1').jqGrid('setGridParam', {
            onSelectRow: function (id) {
                $('#list2')
                    .jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"/sis/modul/mod_pelanggan/kendaraan.php?id="+id,page:1})
                    .trigger('reloadGrid');
                    },
            ondblClickRow: function (id) {
                var rowid = jQuery(this).jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
                jQuery(this).jqGrid('editGridRow', rowid, <?php echo json_encode_jsfunc($g->options["edit_options"])?>);
            }

        });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    onSelectRow: function (id) {
        $('#list2')
            .jqGrid('setGridParam',{url: "/sis/modul/mod_pelanggan/kendaraan.php?id=" + id, page:1})
            .trigger('reloadGrid');
        $('#list2').setSelection($(this).getDataIDs()[0], true);
    }
```

Question though, Why are you initialising and selecting the first row of the subgrid `onSelectRow` and not on `subGridRowExpanded`?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work , I use subgrid as grid. So I initialising onSelectRow not on subGridRowExpanded.